Counting the Ketoret ingredients
Sephardim have a custom to count with the fingers on their right hand each of the 11 ingredients in the Ketoret when reciting the passage every day. Where does this idea come from? And what power does it have

no source for this, but this seems like an obvious possibility. we say it in order to fulfill it, with our mouths taking place of the actions. And we recite חיסר אחת מכל סממניה - חייב מיתה. So it would be awful to accidentally omit an ingredient. Indeed, because of hurry and this accident possibility, that's why the practice emerged to only recite it on Shabbat. Counting them off on your fingers helps catch if you skipped one.

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%94#:~:text=%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%27%20%D7%9C%D7%90%27%2C%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%92%20%D7%97%22%D7%95%20%D7%90%27%20%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%9D.

@joshwaxman I like that explanation thanks

@shmosel How can you highlight and share text like that?

@Kazibácsi  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10256233

This is also minhag Chabad

Kaf hachaim (48, 4) says to do so, quoting the ben ish chai (year 1, mikeitz, s.k. 8). The reasoning is so he will not err.
Interestingly, he says to count only on the right hand, because reciting it is as if one actually brought it, and any service in the beit hamikdash which was performed with the left hand is invalid!

Woah really? What’s the source for that last statement about the left hand? Also is it only the left hand that’s bad, or you can’t use even both hands in the temple?
